# How to serialize the Point

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, polygon

I am trying to serialize the list of Polygons. This class include 3 public fields: amountOfVertexes,List where Stroke -is my own class, and List where Point - is C# class. Unfourtantly I cant serialize it, where I did mistake? 
This is my class

```
    [XmlRoot("CustomPolygon")]
    public class CustomPolygon
    {
    #region Cunstructors
    public CustomPolygon()
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public fields

    [XmlAttribute("amountOfVertexes")]
    public int amountOfVertexes;                   // Количество сторон полигона
    [XmlArray("Points")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Point")]
    public  List<Point> listOfVertexes;            // Список всех вершин
    [XmlArray("Strokes")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Stroke")]
    public List<Stroke> listOfStrokes;             // Список ребер
    #endregion

    #region Private fields
    private PointCollection Points;
    #endregion
```

And I add the same elements in the Stroke

```
  [XmlRoot("Stroke")]
   public class Stroke
   {
    #region Constructors
    public Stroke()
    {
        this.beginPoint = new Point();
        this.endPoint = new Point();
    }
    public Stroke(Point pBegin, Point pEnd)  
    {
        this.beginPoint = pBegin;
        this.endPoint = pEnd;
    }
    #endregion 

    #region Public Member Variables
    [XmlAttribute("beginPoint")]
    public Point beginPoint;            // Начальная точка отрезка 
    [XmlAttribute("endPoint")]
    public Point endPoint;              // Конечная точка отрезка
    #endregion
}
```

But I can't add the same elements (I mean [XmlAttribute] ) to the Point class, because it closed. What I do wrong? I am trying to serialize whitch help of this code:

```
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(saveFileDialogPolygon.FileName))
 {
 XmlSerializer xmlSerializerCustom = new XmlSerializer(typeof (List <CustomPolygon>));
 xmlSerializerCustom.Serialize(writer,listOfCustomPolygons);
 }
 writer.Close();
```

And I got " An error occurred while the reflection type" May be the error because of Point? So, how I can serialize(and desirialze) the standart Point class?

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted. You can accept your own answer if it is the correct solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem in the past, see: 
[Build a Custom Serialization as String in System.Xml.Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17014475/1233788).

my solution adapted to your case would be something like this:

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<Point> listOfVertexes;

    [XmlArray("Points")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Point")]
    public string[] listOfVertexesString
    {
        get { return listOfVertexes.Select(s => s.X + "," + s.Y).ToArray(); }
        set
        {
            listOfVertexes = value
                .Select(s => new Point
                {
                    X = int.Parse(s.Split(',')[0]),
                    Y = int.Parse(s.Split(',')[1])
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

That will generate a XML like this:

```
  <!-- something before -->
    <Points>
      <Point>0,1</Point>
      <Point>4,10</Point>
      <Point>3,5</Point>
    </Points>
  <!-- something after -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! I think it is good experience! But the proble was not in Serialize of Object Point! The problem was in this code

```
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName))
                {
                    // Найдем количество полигонов в Xml-файле
                    XmlDocument loadedXml = new XmlDocument();
                    string directory = openFileDialog.FileName;
                    loadedXml.Load(reader); **// I USE IT, BUT NO CLOSE!**
                    XmlNodeList polygonNodeList = loadedXml.GetElementsByTagName("CustomPolygon");

               if (polygonNodeList.Count > 1)
                    for (int i = 0; i < polygonNodeList.Count; i++)
                    {
                       // List <CustomPolygon> listcp= new List<CustomPolygon>();
             XmlSerializer xmlReader = new XmlSerializer(typeof (List<CustomPolygon>));
                 var listcp = (List<CustomPolygon>)xmlReader.Deserialize(reader);
                        }
               else
                    {
                        XmlSerializer xmlReaderResult = new XmlSerializer((typeof (CustomPolygon)));
                        CustomPolygon loadedResultPolygon = (CustomPolygon) xmlReaderResult.Deserialize(reader); **// MORE OVER I USE IT IN THIS PLACE, WITHOUT CLOSE()** BEFORE
                        resultOfTwoPolygonsUnion = loadedResultPolygon;
                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of it, I should use like this:

```
            StreamReader file=new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName);
            // Найдем количество полигонов в Xml-файле
            XmlDocument loadedXml = new XmlDocument();
            loadedXml.Load(file);
            XmlNodeList polygonNodeList = loadedXml.GetElementsByTagName("CustomPolygon");
            file.Close();

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog.FileName))
            {

                XmlSerializer xmlReader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomPolygon));
                CustomPolygon resultPolygon = new CustomPolygon();
                resultPolygon = (CustomPolygon)xmlReader.Deserialize(reader);

            }
```